# How to get facebook user information in API version 2.6 in ios?

Tags: ios, facebook

Is it possible to change the `Facebook API version` from `2.6` to `2.2` in `iOS`. I am not able to get all user information in `version 2.6`. I used current `SDK` `version` and also `FacebookSDKs-iOS-20150813`. Both SDKs are not giving me user information excluding id and username.

Answer (score 0):

You can´t downgrade an App to a lower App, you can only upgrade it to a newer one. Downgrading would not make any sense anyway, it´s better not to use stuff that is deprecated.

Upgrade Tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/api_versioning/

You do not neet to downgrade anyway, you only need to use the fields parameter: `/me?fields=name,first_name,...`

It´s called "Declarative Fields" and came with v2.4 of the Graph API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

Comment: actually i want a user information on custom facebook login button. whenever i clicked on button it give me only id and username other fields like first_name are null..please help me regards this

Comment: that´s not just a suggestion, it´s a complete answer. everything you need to know is in my anser, please read it carefully. declarative fields is exactly what you need.

Comment: i replaced "email" with "first_name". try that api call with the fields parameter.

Comment: Note also that the 2.2 API will be unavailable after March 217 (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog) so downgrading would be a very short term solution, even if it were needed.